# OBiee dashboard promt

Tags: dashboard, prompt, obiee, lov

I am trying to populate the list of values in dashboard prompt with my SQL query , but i am getting failed to load error.
Since the column i want is not there in any subject area I have used the below query:
"select batch_number from EGI_IMPORT_BATCHES_VL"

Kindly help me to get the list of values populated

[Query Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKdv0.png)
[Rrror message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dLMd.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's simply not how OBI works. You work with models - metadata from the RPD. You do not work with SQL queries. It's an analytical platform, not SQL Developer with a GUI. You can't write physical SQL for prompts. The "SQL" you write there is LSQL - Logical Structured Query Language. Not the "Oracle Database Structured Query Language".

Edit: No, you can't shoehorn things into a prompt which are not in the subject area. A prompt is based on a specific subject area for a reason.

Comment: Could you pls let me know if there is any way to populate such values which are not available in Subject areas in the list of values .(dashboard propmt)

Comment: Added to the answer above